# Trying to create a aws S3 policy to allow creating a S3 and only allowed to delete with specific tag name

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, policy, tagging

I have been able to figure out how to limit a policy to creating a s3, but have not been able to figure out the json for onl allowing the user to only be able to delete with specific TAG.

Updated:

I need to create a policy say for the user to be able to create S3 Buckets, Subnets, and LambdaFunctions. I can do this easily, but I am trying to add a restriction so the user can only delete something that has a specific TAG. This part I struggle to do. John can create S3 Bucket, but can't delete any S3Buckets unless they are labeled "ExampleBucket".

I am probably not explaining correct. So restrict by allowing user to delete by tag name or restrict by allowing deleting what the user created.

Comment: So, you've written an IAM policy? Or an S3 bucket policy? Can you include the policy, masking any sensitive info (e.g. your bucket name and account number).

Comment: What do you mean by "creating a s3"? A bucket? An object?

Comment: I need to create a policy say for the user to be able to create S3 Buckets, Subnets, and LambdaFunctions. I can do this easily, but I am trying to add a restriction so the user can only delete something that has a specific TAG.  This part I struggle to do. 

John can create S3 Bucket, but can't delete any S3Buckets unless they are labeled "ExampleBucket".

I am probably not explaining correct So restrict by allowing delete by tag name or restrict by allowing deleting what the user created.